# Use of WHEN clause in SQLLDR

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am loading datasets containing around 25 billion rows each into one of our databases.
With that much data I don't want to load rows which are not required, so I added a WHERE clause to the load.
The data consists of rows of XYZ values, when Z = -9999 it means the point is undefined and can be omitted.

Adding **WHERE Z <> -9999** gives this error ...

```
SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 5.
Expecting quoted string or hex identifier, found "-".
  WHEN Z <> -9999
```

Without the WHERE clause it runs fine

**Data:**

```
44790.301538192,54665.413037326,-9999
44791.301474866,54665.387827518,-9999
44792.30141154,54665.36261771,-9999
44793.301348214,54665.337407902,-9999
```

Target Table:

```
CREATE TABLE LIDAR_DSM_XYZ_1M
(
  PK_ID     INTEGER,
  TILE      VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  GEOMETRY  MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY
)
```

Control File:

```
OPTIONS(DIRECT=TRUE)
UNRECOVERABLE LOAD DATA
 INFILE 'su9498_dsm_1m.xyz'
 APPEND
 INTO TABLE LIDAR_DSM_XYZ_1M
  WHEN Z <> -9999
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 TRAILING NULLCOLS (
  TILE CONSTANT 'su9498_dsm_1m',
  GEOMETRY COLUMN OBJECT 
  (SDO_GTYPE       CONSTANT 3001, 
   SDO_POINT COLUMN OBJECT
   (X            FLOAT EXTERNAL, 
    Y            FLOAT EXTERNAL,
    Z            FLOAT EXTERNAL
   )
  )
 )
```

Comment: Check out the `code` button in the question editor. :)

Comment: I did that, prefixed with 4 spaces as per instructions but it just ignored it

Comment: You also have to have an empty line before the code segment. And you can mark text and then click the code button then it will be done for you.

Comment: Tried that to. Doesn't work for me. I suspect somewhat dated  IE7 browser I have to use at work may have something to do with it

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005657), the literal must be a string, a hex code, or BLANKS.

The error message actually tells you that:

> Expecting quoted string or hex identifier, found "-"

Use:

```
WHEN Z <> '-9999'
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. I get a different error then   SQL*Loader-403: Referenced column Z not present in table LIDAR_DSM_XYZ_1M.

Comment: Then it sounds like your problem is "how to reference a column". Try the positional specification: WHEN (3) <> '-9999'

Comment: Unfortunately the positional spec refers the the character position in the input line rather than the field. However, it does make a rather klugey workaround possible because the records only occur in one of two formats I can text character 31 and 33 to see if they are '-'.  Not ideal but deleting the records from a table with 25 billion rows takes forever.

Comment: An external table approach always makes this sort of thing more tolerable. For one thing, you can only do AND in the conditional load clause.